# AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, nsnotificationcenter

```
  NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"thoughtcastAnimate_v02" withExtension:@"mov"];



    // create an AVPlayer
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];

    // create a player view controller
    AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];

    controller.showsPlaybackControls = false;


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object: player];//edited

    controller.player = player;
    // show the view controller
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    controller.view.frame = self.view.frame;

    [player play];
```

itemDidFinishPlaying is never called ?!

I don't understand why.
Perhaps I have an invalid NSNotificationCenter issue. Or maybe one of it's parameters. Unsure.

Comment: If you change `object: player` to `object: nil` does anything improve?

Comment: `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` is a notification from `AVPlayerItem`. So you can use `object:player.currentItem` if you want to make sure you only receive notifications from the player you created.